# What happens to child threads if I do Thread.sleep(10000) in main method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, jakarta-ee

I have created some callable threads in a for loop, in my main method and started all of them.

After starting all threads I have `Thread.sleep(10000)`. In this case what happens to my child callable threads.

psudocode:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Map<String, String> columnNames_TypesMap = tableUtil.getColumnNamesAndTypesFromOracleDB(toTable);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

        Set<Future<String>> values = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Future<String>, Boolean>());
        Future<String> value = null;
        boolean valueSizeLogged = false;
        long preValuesSize = values.size();

        outer: while (true) {
            //In the below method I am reducing values size.
            count = tableUtil.checkIfAllRowsCopied(values, count, totalNoOfRecordsInFromTable);

            if (values.size() > 5) {
                logger.info("****** Hence we do not create new threads. We do wait for the created threads to compelte");
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);//Here I am putting my main thread to sleep
                continue outer;
            }

            for (int indexForThread = 1; indexForThread <= 15; indexForThread++) {
                startingRange = endingRanges + 1;
                endingRanges = endingRanges + maxNoOfRecordsPerThread;

                Callable<String> callable2 = new InsertionCallable(as400SchemaName + "." + fromTable, startingRange, endingRanges, columnNames_TypesMap, toTable);
                value = executor.submit(callable2);//Child Thread
                values.add(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the above code first i have created 15 Threads. in the second loop(outer while), I am doing Thread.sleep() if values size is greater than 5, at this point of time what will happen to the created child threads? Will Child threads also goes to Sleep mode or what happens to Child Threads.

Kindly help. Your help will be highly appreciable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The child threads are not affected by the parent thread sleeping (or terminating, or pretty much anything else). They will happily chug along.